# Get specific cell out of named column using INDIRECT?

Tags: excel, ms-office, worksheet, excel-indirect

I have 12 columns in worksheet A, which are named after months of the calendar (via name-field).
In worksheet B I want to display certain cell-values out of the those months-columns, for example:

```
=INDIRECT("'worksheet-a'!"january[specific_cell]"")
```

What is the right syntax to specify any cell within a named column?
The brackets used in the example above are just to point out the problem.

Right now I am using

```
=INDIRECT("'worksheet-a'!"&$B$3&"")
```

B3 is the field where I will trigger which column to display, like "jan" or "dec".
This works pretty neatly but only get me a 1:1 copy of worksheet A. I want to be able to re-arrange data freely in worksheet B, not just copy the whole layout cell for cell. Therefor I am trying to get specific cells.

I want to be able to display data from **K10** in worksheet A in cell **K50** in worksheet B. Not in K10 as well.

Comment: It looks like you might use INDEX/MATCH or HLOOKUP. How do you determine the row from which to return data?

Comment: How will you define the [specific_cell] in your formula?. If B3 choses the column? What chooses the cell in the column? If I understood you right, in the function you mentioned you're using, the output will be `=INDIRECT("'worksheet-a'!jan")` referring the entire column not a cell.

Comment: That's exactly what I have been trying to ask. Currently I am able to dynamically define the column as a whole. How to I define the specific cell? It was easy if it was just something like "A4". But I want to define something like "jan4".